# Link two equations from piecewise in point

Tags: fitting, list-manipulation

I have some system for fitting my data:

```
fitModeluv = Piecewise[{{A0uv - Auv Exp[-(t/\[Tau])], 
 t < t0uv}, {B0uv + Buv Exp[-(t/\[Tau])], t >= t0uv}}, A0uv - Auv Exp[-(t0uv/\[Tau])] - Buv Exp[-(t0uv/\[Tau])]];
```

This system fits *(green line)*  data *(blue)* like:
[image]

**2 questions:**

1. How can I connet 2 equations in one point (*red points on the picture*)?

[image]

2. When I substituting values in the system (by `Range[]`), output is very awful and i can't minus this array from different list of values. How to fix it?

Comment: You need to put a restriction on the parameters so that they meet at a single point.  Specifically you want `t0uv = \[Tau] Log[(Auv + Buv)/(A0uv - B0uv)]`.  This is from equating the two pieces at `t0uv`.

Answer (score 5):

You'll need to restrict the parameters so that the two curves meet at a single point:

```
t0uv = t0uv /. (Solve[A0uv - Auv Exp[-(t0uv/τ)] == B0uv + Buv Exp[-(t0uv/τ)],
 t0uv] /. C[1] -> 0)[[1]]
(* τ Log[(Auv + Buv)/(A0uv - B0uv)] *)
```

For example, first generate some data:

```
SeedRandom[1235];
A0uvInit = 49.273;
AuvInit = 13.273;
τInit = 100;
B0uvInit = 37.006;
BuvInit = 36.472;
t0uvInit = 140;
data = Table[{t, Piecewise[{{A0uvInit - AuvInit Exp[-(t/τInit)], t < t0uvInit}, 
  {B0uvInit + BuvInit Exp[-(t/τInit)], t >= t0uvInit}}]}, {t, 0, 250}];
data[[All, 2]] = data[[All, 2]] + RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 251];
```

Fit data to piecewise curve...

```
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data,
   Piecewise[{{A0uv - Auv Exp[-(t/τ)], t < t0uv}, 
     {B0uv + Buv Exp[-(t/τ)], t >= t0uv}}],
   {{A0uv, A0uvInit}, {Auv, AuvInit}, {B0uv, B0uvInit}, {Buv, BuvInit}, {τ, τInit}}, t];

nlm["BestFitParameters"]
(* {A0uv -> 49.59797043559751, Auv -> 13.465589303011921,
    B0uv -> 36.869607720932656, Buv -> 34.24815518555274,
    τ -> 103.17795183868176} *)
t0uv /. nlm["BestFitParameters"]
(* 136.33797461279067 *)
```

Plot the results

```
Show[ListPlot[data], Plot[nlm[t], {t, 0, 250}]]
```

[image: Data and curve fit]